# Access data from View based on Oracle XML Type column

Tags: oracle, xmltype

I am trying to get the data from a Oracle View created on XML Type column.
e.g: Following is the XSD:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="MsrFact" type="MsrNode"/>
<xsd:complexType name="MsrNode">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="shipTo" type="MsrValue"/>
<xsd:element name="billTo" type="MsrValue"/>
<xsd:element name="FormulaeItem"  type="MsrValue" maxOccurs="10"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="MsrValue">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="name"   type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:integer"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Inserted xml is:

```
<MsrFact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

 <MsrNode>
  <shipTo>
     <name>shipTo</name>
   </shipTo>
   <billTo>
     <name>billTo</name>
   </billTo>
  <FormulaeItem>
    <name>FormulaeItem1</name>
  </FormulaeItem>
  <FormulaeItem>
     <name>FormulaeItem2</name>
     <street>100</street>
  </FormulaeItem>
  <FormulaeItem>
     <name>FormulaeItem3</name>
   </FormulaeItem>
 </MsrNode>
</MsrFact>
```

Table:
`temptab(
ogrid number(10),
xdata xmltype);`

VIEW:
`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`
`MsrFactView(orgid,shipTo,shipToR, billTo,billToR, FormulaeItem,FormulaeItemR)`
`AS SELECT ogrid,`
`extractValue(xdata, '/MsrFact/shipTo/name'),`
`extractValue(xdata, '/MsrFact/shipTo/street'),`
`extractValue(xdata, '/MsrFact/billTo/name'),`
`extractValue(xdata, '/MsrFact/billTo/street'),`
`extractValue(xdata, '/MsrFact/FormulaeItem/name'),`
`extractValue(xdata, '/MsrFact/FormulaeItem/street')`
`FROM temptab;`

I cannot write a direct select query on this view as it gives the error
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Is there any way to get the data from this view?
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

extractValue only extracts a single value from the give path, but as the FormulaeItem can be many, you can't use extractValue here.
Besides, using extractValue is a old and not recommended way for querying XML. You should use the new XMLTable approach.

```
create or replace view MsrFactView as
select tt.ogrid,
st.name shiptoName, st.street shiptoStreeet,
bt.name billtoName ,bt.street billtoStreet,
fi.name formulaeitemname ,fi.street formulaeitemstreet
FROM
temptab tt,
XMLTABLE(
    '/MsrFact/MsrNode'
    passing tt.xdata
    columns
        shipto  XMLTYPE path '/MsrNode/shipTo'
        billto  XMLTYPE path '/MsrNode/billTo'
        formulaeitem XMLTYPE path '/MsrNode/FormulaeItem'
) nd,
XMLTable (
    '/shipTo'
    passing nd.shipto
    columns
    name varchar2(4000) path '/shipTo/name'
    street number path '/shipTo/street'
) st,
XMLTABLE (
    '/billTo'
    passing nd.billto
    columns
    name varchar2(4000) path '/billTo/name'
    street number path '/billTo/street'
) bt,
XMLTable (
    '/FormulaeItem'
    passing nd.formulaeitem
    columns
    name varchar2(4000) path '/FormulaeItem/name'
    street number path '/FormulaeItem/street'
) fi
/
```

One thing to remember though is that you won't get one row per one 'MsrNode', as you have 1-n FormulaeItem per MsrNode. Think of it as a SQL query joining 2 tables having a 1-n relationship. Just like in that case, you will get 'n' rows per every 1 row of the parent table.

So in your case, per every MsrNode, you will get as many rows in your view, as the count of FormulaeItems in that node.